# Inline Perl within my Java... Inline::Java::PerlInterpreter not working?

Tags: java, perl

I need to make a call to the [Image::ExifTool](http://p3rl.org/Image%3a%3aExifTool) Perl module via Java. The only viable solution I have found is [Inline::Java::PerlInterpreter](http://p3rl.org/Inline%3a%3aJava%3a%3aPerlInterpreter), yet when trying to install via cpan, [I always get the error](http://pastebin.com/e760PB9G):

```
/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): In function `__libc_csu_init':
(.text 0x18): undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS): relocation R_386_GOTOFF against undefined hidden symbol `__init_array_end' can not be used when making a shared object
```

I have filed a bug, but am yet to gain a response.

Does anyone have an alternative in mind? Something that would allow me to pass a byte array to a Perl function, make a call to the Image::ExifTool module, and return a string array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone have an alternative in mind?

Yes. Use a native Java EXIF handler like [one of these](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7485).

Comment: _Sanselen_ of the Apache Commons project was perfect.